# XSLT 3.0: Conditional setting of <xsl:accumulator>

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I would ordinarily like to set different `<xsl:accumulator>`*s* in response to the  results of `<xsl:if test="foo">`.

**Problem**: `<xsl:accumulator>` must be a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>` or `<xsl:transform>`.

Said another way, the accumulator cannot be in a template where condition tests could be performed.

**Question**: Is there a way to change accumulator specs at run time, based on what is found in the source document?

The accumulator is similar to:

```
<xsl:accumulator 
    name="f:accumulate-string-length"
    post-descent="f:accum-string-length"
    as="xs:integer"
    initial-value="0">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule 
        match="*" 
        new-value="$value + string-length()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

What I'd like to change at run time based on the source document is the `@match=""`.

**Update** (response to comments): If the document tests to have a `article/div` structure, I would like the accumulator @match to be `article/div`, if the document tests to have `section/div` structure, I'd want the accumulator @match to be `section/div`.

Sometimes my documents vary, and like like to adjust on the fly.

Comment: I smell an X-Y-problem. What would you like to change it *to*, and why?

Comment: I haven't done much with accumulators but as far as I understand them, the `match` attribute is a pattern and, like with a template, you define that pattern when writing a stylesheet. The main feature given to restrict an accumulator is the `applies-to` attribute of the `xsl:accumulator`. Also you can use predicates and variables in patterns.

Comment: You have not really explained what you want to do, you want to check `<xsl:if test="foo">`, so you want to check whether a `foo` element exists, but you have not explained the context node for that check and you have not told us how you want to change the match pattern. So it is a bit difficult to tell whether your requirement can be solved somehow with XSLT 3.0 or not.

Comment: Would `match="article/div | section/div"` do for your types of documents?

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I have some concerns about documents that may come in with both of those.  I may put <body> in also.

Comment: I would be inclined to have two different accumulators that apply to the two different kinds of source document.